# Fetching Data From MySQL with $this->db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

So, I am trying to get the IMDb id for the from the table called videos. I tried it with these these are giving me error.
Code 1:

```
      $imdb_id =  $this->db->get_where('videos', array('imdbid'))->result_array();
```

Code 2:

```
      $imdb_id =  $this->db->get('videos','imdbid');
```

code 3:

```
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM videos;");
      $row = $query->row(0, 'videos');
      $imdb_id = $row['imdbid'];
```

Here is a screenshot of database table. Thank you for your contribution in advance.
[image]

Comment: do you only want `imdbid` column from `videos` table right?

Comment: no, i don't want the whole column. It's a post meta for my cms, I just want to make sure the post can show the the related imdbid, the video_id is the post id.

Comment: but your description is not matching with your last comment, try to show your error part too, and please elaborate more on your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain the error and output expectations.

you want only one return data or multiple data?

This **Codeigniter 3** right?

the current code you are using is incorrect :

Code 1 :

```
// will get only one data with where condition
// videos_id = 1
$video_id = 1;
$data =  $this->db->get_where('videos', array('videos_id'=>$video_id))->result_array();
$imdb_id = $data[0]['imdbid'];
```

Code 2 :

```
// will get all data without where condition
// must use loop foreach
$data =  $this->db->get('videos')->result_array();
```